# What does read -r do?

Tags: linux

```
String="This is a string of words."

read -r -a Words <<< "$String"
```

I use the `man read` command to check, but there is no option at all. I also try to search pattern `/-r`. It comes up with no result. How can I find what does `-r` actually do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` is a shell builtin command and you can find information about it from `man bash`:

```
read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
...
-r     Backslash does not act as an escape character.  The backslash is considered to be part of the line.  In particular, a backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation.
```

Comment: Btw, how do you find `read` quickly? The description of `man bash` is super long.